# What is the cache's role when writing to memory?

Tags: caching, memory, pthreads

I have a function that does very little reading, but a lot of writing to RAM. When I run it multiple times on the same core (the main thread), it runs about 5x as fast than if I launch the function on a new thread every run (which doesn't guarantee the same core is used between runs), as I launch and join between runs.

This suggests the cache is being used heavily for the write process, but I don't understand how. I thought the cache was only useful for reads.

Comment: If you saturate your write-buffer with writes to partial cachelines, you'll stall until the cachelines are brought in from memory. You may be able to avoid this by using non-temporal stores and/or always writing full cachelines.

Comment: That sounds deserving of an *Answer* to me, EOF ... What do you mean by "non-temporal stores," and so on.  Sounds like you've got a lot to say here.  **:-)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modern processors usually have write-buffers. The reason is that writes are, to a first approximation, pure sinks. The processor doesn't usually have to wait for the store to reach the coherent memory hierarchy before it executes the next instruction.

(Aside: Obviously stores are *not* pure sinks. A later read from the written-to memory location should return the written value, so the processor must snoop the write-buffer, and either stall the read or forward the written value to it)

Obviously such buffer(s) are of finite size, so when the buffers are full the next store in the program can't be executed and stalls until a slot in the buffer is made available by an older store becoming architecturally visible.

Ordinarily, the way a write leaves the buffer is when the value is written to cache (since a lot of writes *are* actually read back again quickly, think of the program stack as an example). If the write only sets part of the cacheline, the rest of the cacheline must remain unmodified, so consequently it must be loaded from the memory hierarchy.

There are ways to avoid loading the old cacheline, like non-temporal stores, write-combining memory or cacheline-zeroing instructions.

Non-temporal stores and write-combining memory combine adjacent writes to fill a whole cacheline, sending the new cacheline to the memory hierarchy to replace the old one.

POWER has an instruction that zeroes a full cacheline (`dcbz`), which also removes the need to load the old value from memory.

x86 with AVX512 has cacheline-sized registers, which suggests that an aligned `zmm`-register store *could* avoid loading the old cacheline (though I do not know whether it does).

Note that many of these techniques are not consistent with the usual memory-ordering of the respective processor architectures. Using them may require additional fences/barriers in multi-threaded operation.